# Discrete implementation of the PI controller

Tags: discrete-signals, c++, pid, discretization

I have been implementing discrete PI controller in the incremental (velocity) form in C++.
I have been looking for the anti-windup mechanism. One idea which I have can be described by
following pseudocode:

```
    integral_gain = proportional_gain*sampling_period/(2*integral_time_constant);

    // e(k)
    error = reference_value - actual_value;

    // dup(k)= kp*[e(k) - e(k-1)]
    proportional_increment = proportional_gain * (error - error_previous);
    // trapezoidal integration rule i.e. dui(k) = ki*[e(k) + e(k-1)]
    integral_increment = integral_gain * (error + error_previous);
    // du(k) = dup(k) + dui(k)
    action_increment = proportional_increment + integral_increment;
    // u(k) = u(k-1) + du(k)
    tmp = action_previous + action_increment;

    // anti-windup
    if (tmp > action_max) {
      action = action_max;
    } else if (tmp < action_min) {
      action = action_min;
    } else {
      action = tmp;
    }

    // u(k-1) = u(k)
    action_previous = action;
    // e(k-1) = e(k)
    error_previous = error;
```

In math:

Let $x_k$ be the "action".  Further, define an anti-windup function as

$$f_{aw}(x) = \begin{cases}
x_{max} & x > x_{max} \\
x_{min} & x < x_{min} \\
x & \mathrm {otherwise}
 \end{cases} $$

Then calculate $x_k$ from:

$$
\Delta p = k_p (e_k - e_{k-1}) \\
\Delta i = k_i (e_k + e_{k-1}) \\
x_k = f_{aw} \left ( x_{k-1} + \Delta p + \Delta i \right)
$$

I am not really sure whether the anti-windup mechanism mentioned above will be appropriate despite the fact that the incremental form is used. Can anybody help?

Comment: "*One idea which I have*" -- why reinvent the wheel when there are already [known implementations](https://www.scilab.org/pid-anti-windup-schemes) (plus, Xcos allows you to enter C/C++ code to verify)?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen thank you for useful link. In case I understand correctly the mentioned antiwind-up schemes are for the positional form of the PID controller. I have been looking for antiwind-up scheme for velocity form of the PID controller.

Comment: you don't have an anti-windup scheme by the way, you only perform a saturation.

Comment: @Ben I know that saturation isn't sufficient in case the positional form of the PI is used. But I think that it could be correct anti wind-up mechanism in case the velocity form of PI is used due to the fact that only the increment of the integral is calculated in that case.

Comment: you don't actually have an integrator, come to think of it...

Comment: @Ben do you think that my implementation is totally wrong or only the anti wind-up is wrong?

Comment: Your implementation in general seems wrong.. Ask yourself, where is your integrator?

Comment: @Ben in my opinion the integration is actually done in this line of code: 'tmp = action_previous + action_increment;'

Comment: @Steve You have a block schematic there, why not follow it? If the rest of the schematics obscure it, here's the [bare-bones of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dhpE.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define "appropriate".

Yes, the output of the controller will be limited to between your `action_max` and `action_min` -- this is good.  Since your output is also your integrator state, you'll be effecting anti-windup.  If I'm not horribly mistaken, if your output *is* saturated, as soon as the error term starts pointing in the opposite direction of the limit it's at, then it'll back away from that limit.

So you have an anti-windup method that is a good candidate.

However, anti-windup is a nonlinear control law, which is appropriate to use when you're dealing with some plant nonlinearity or some optimality criterion that is not least-square-error.  *Usually* you're dealing with actuator saturation, and *usually* you just want a stable system and you're willing to let it take a bit extra-long to settle when it has to move a long way.  In that case then, yes, this control law may be "appropriate".

But ultimately, the "appropriateness" of a controller depends on your plant, how it's being used, and if you're working in a team, whether your colleagues agree that it's appropriate*.  It's an opinion call.  So you need to determine if it's appropriate by your lights, and if you're in a team, you need to convince the team that you're right.

* Because the best control rule ever isn't any good at all if your boss won't let you implement it.